# SQL query not returning the result with the proper capitalization

Tags: python, sql, azure-sql-database

[image: I currently have a table called WorkSegment with the following fields]

[image: I currently have a table called Project with the following fields]

When I execute the query

```
"""SELECT WorkSegment.*, CONVERT(varchar(10), submitDate, 101), Projects.name  AS submitDate 
FROM WorkSegment 
LEFT JOIN Projects ON WorkSegment.projectId=Projects.projectId 
WHERE employeeId='{id}'""".format(id=eID)"
```

the result for the project Name is invalid.

For example: If a project has the name 'Alief Forest North P&D-COH FY17', it will return 'Alief Forest North P&D-Coh Fy17'. It does not return with the proper capitalization. How can I modify the sql query to return with proper capitalization?

Comment: What's the proper capitalization? What rule should be observed about the capitalization of the result?

Comment: There's nothing in your query that will change the case of any strings. It must be that way in the database.

Comment: @NickODell It should just return the name that is currently present in the database for the appropriate projectId. Currently the name is Alief Forest North P&D-COH FY17 with COH and FY capitalized but the query returns only the first letter as capitalized. If i do a basic query such as "Select * from projects" it returns with the proper capitalization but in the query above it does not

Comment: @Barmar It is currently that way in the database but i seems as tho the query is "pre-processing" it and only capitalizing the first letters

Comment: I've never heard of a SQL database that did that kind of automatic capitalization.

Comment: Maybe you have a trigger that's pre-processing it when you insert?

Comment: @Barmar I have verified that what is inserted in the database is correct but what is retrieved using the query above returns (272, 331053, 16, datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 5, 0, 0), 'Administration', 10.0, '', 'Architecture Conceptual', ' ', '4', True, '04/05/2022', 'Alief Forest North P&D-Coh Fy17') and as u can see the returned project name using leftjoin does not return it exactly as it appears in the database. Also I am using Azure SQL Database if thats helpful

Comment: How are you able to verify it if it always returns it with initial capitals? Does this only happen when you use `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: BTW, don't use string formatting to substitute into SQL queries. Use a prepared statement with placeholders and parameters passed to `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: @Barmar I could verify it because on my website i have a dropdown menu which is populated by all active projects. The list for the dropdown is populated using the query "SELECT * FROM [Projects] WHERE activeStatus='Y' ORDER BY projectId ASC" and this query returns the name and everything else as seen in the database. This also happened when I used Inner Join as well but yes it is only in instances where the SQL statement is retrieving the project name using JOIN. It is weird tho because there is another table called Company and using JOIN retrieves the company name properly so i'm not sure

Comment: You don't really have `Projects.name AS submitDate`, do you?  Was that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why a database would change the format because you're joining.'

Comment: Please post the 2 queries and the different output for the same row & column of the same table. Thank you